# Is there anything wrong with reassigning a reactor Publisher Mono like this?

Tags: java, project-reactor

Is there anything wrong with this?

```
public static void test3() {
  Mono<String> mono = Mono.just("");

  System.out.println(mono);
  for(int i=1; i<10; i++) {
    mono = updateMono(mono, i);
    System.out.println(mono);
  }

  mono.subscribe((s) -> System.out.println(s));
}

private static Mono<String> updateMono(Mono<String> mono, int i) {
  return mono
      .flatMap(s -> {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
          return Mono.just(s + "-" + Integer.toString(i));
        } else {
          return mono;
        }
      });
}
```

It prints out the expected output

> -2-4-6-8

I guess I'm asking if there might be anything unexpected or side-effects that I'm not considering

Comment: Like what? Reassigning to `Mono.just(s + "-" + Integer.toString(i))` or `mono = updateMono(mono, i);`

Comment: Anything odd about `mono = updateMono(mono, i)`?

Comment: Well, same question I suppose. You are chaining either `Mono::just` or doing nothing with the same reference returned from `updateMono`. I have seen chaining `Mono::just` done plenty but I must question why you are doing that. It will create a stack of Monos and that gets handled no problem, but if you can avoid that I personally think it is cleaner.

Comment: Glad to know nothing egregious here except maybe performance issue. If you know how I can chain it together while maintaining this semantic, I'm open to the idea.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. You loop over a set of values and create a queue of monos 10 deep. Does the order matter? You're expected output of -2-4-6-8 only works because  `s + "-" + Integer.toString(i)` concatenates strings. If you are using a class then what does `+` mean for that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the main point being queried here is the use of the imperative loop to update the `mono` reference.

There's nothing *wrong* with it per-se, but I find it best avoided if possible from a style perspective - it means you can't just return a single reactive chain, you have to declare it, imperatively modify it an arbitrary number of times, then return it.

Clearly this is a contrived example, but there's usually different strategies you can take that result in clearer code, depending on the situation:

- You could opt to use a `Flux` and reduce it down instead, something like:

  ```
   Flux.range(1, 9)
           .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
           .map(i -> Integer.toString(i))
           .reduce((i1, i2) -> i1 + "-" + i2)
           .subscribe(System.out::println);
  ```
- You could refactor out the loop into a separate method, then use `transform`, referencing that method, to at least keep the flow of your main reactive chain going;
- If the "real-world" example is more naturally recursive rather than iterative, then switching to use a `Flux` and then making use of `expand()` or `expandDeep()` would be the most logical choice.

Sure, if it seems clear and you're happy with it, then there's definitely far worse things you could do in a reactive pipeline - but in most real-world cases I've come across, there's usually a better way of presenting the problem which avoids the need for that imperative loop.